# How to write a BATCH variable into a .txt file?

Tags: batch-file, variables

So, I am making a batch file that takes your variable and puts it into a .txt file. It always just says "ECHO is off." in the .txt file.
--------------------------------------------------------------My code:

```
@echo off
set /p 1="k"
echo %1%
@echo %1% >> 1.txt
pause
exit
```

Output in the .txt file:

```
ECHO is off.
```

If you can help, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: A variable name may include any of the following characters:
A-Z, a-z, 0-9, # $ ' ( ) * + , - . ? @ [ ] _ ` { } ~
The first character of the name **must not be numeric**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to store it as a .bat to be able to load in variables by using Call. Such as:

After defining the variable/s:

```
(
ECHO @ECHO OFF
ECHO Set "variable=%variable%"
ECHO GOTO :EOF
) >example.bat
```

Then, to retrieve any stored variables:

```
CALL "example.bat"
```

This method will support any number of Variables
in the field between (
and
)

If you strictly want to stick with .txt, you can use much the same method to store values:

```
(
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
) >example.txt
```

And to reassign:

```
<example.txt (
Set /p var1=
Set /p var2=
)
```

As you can see though, If your dealing with multiple Variables, you make more work for yourself when reassigning variables by using .txt

Answer (score 0):

%1, %2, etc is used when the variable was received when OPENING the batch file.
In this case, we could use anything BUT 1, 2, 3, etc  so I'm using X

```
@echo off
REM set /p X="K"
set /p X="Question for the user?"
echo %X%
@echo %X% >> 1.txt
pause
exit
```

[see this for more info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm)  the numbers are reserved for command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Variables such as %0, %1, %2 and so on are reserved for parameters that your script might use.

If you run your script as such:

```
Yourscript 123
```

You'd see inside your 1.txt file there would be **123**, because you stored the second parameter you have passed inside your script, which was variable %1 or %1%

So in order to pass data to a variable while giving input inside the script, you need to change your variable to something else, for example:

```
@echo off
set /p input=Your input:
echo %input% >>1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution with putting them into brackets

```
(
%var%
) >> save.sav
```

It works really well, thanks to all of the people wanting to help me!